# error while pushing back pointer vector elements to non pointer vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

I am trying to push back elements of pointer vector `ptrVctor` to nonpointer vector `myvector2` through below for loop in function `full` when the input words size is greater than or equal to 5 but its not happening. When I enter less than 5 words program runs fine. But when I enter more than 5 words program didnt worked as expected but it just terminates.

Main.hpp:

```
#ifndef WORDS_WORDS1_H
#define WORDS_WORDS1_H

#endif //WORDS_WORDS1_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
template <class T>
class MyVector {
public:
    void full(int i){
        if (i >= 5) {//

            for (int j=0; j<ptrVctor->size(); j++){
                myvector2.push_back((*ptrVctor)[j]);//has problem
            }
            delete ptrVctor;
            ptr_cout++;
        }
    }
    void setItems2( T &a){
        if (ptr_cout==0){
            ptrVctor->push_back(a);
        }
        else{
            myvector2.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    int getUsed2 (){
        if (ptr_cout==0)
            return ptrVctor->size();
        else
            return myvector2.size();
    }
    void setUsed2 (int a){
        used2 = a;
    }
private:
    int used2 =0;
    int ptr_cout =0;
    vector<T>* ptrVctor = new vector<T>();
    vector<T> myvector2;
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "main.hpp"
int main()
{
    MyVector<string> v;
    int count = 0;
    string word;
    while (cin >> word) {

        count += 1;
        v.setUsed2(count);
        v.setItems2(word);
        v.full(count);
    }
    cout << "Total: " << v.getUsed2() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a loop outside of any function - that is not allowed

Comment: public loop??? lol

Comment: And what is the error message? The answer is probably already on your screen.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of [consturctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)?

Comment: Why? You are doing something strange. Can you explain what is the rationale to have this?

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually code was big, loop was in a function. By mistake i just copied for loop without the function. Have edited question and included function there.

Comment: what is `ptr_cout`? you have not initialized it.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. This code will not compile or exceute, much less help us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: [compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/adWa7Wo79), please show a [mre] including the full error message or how the code is not behaving as you expect

Comment: have added working program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you enter `5`, in the function `int full(int i )`, your program deletes `ptrVctor`.

When you then enter `6`, the `ptrVctor` is already deleted, but you use `ptrVctor->size()` so  it just terminates.

Answer (score 1):

`myvector2` is an instance variable not a static one. This means you cannot initialize or modify that variable without creating an instance of `MyVector`.

You should perform the `for` loop instruction inside a method or a constructor. I would suggest you learn and clarify your concepts on how classes and their instances work.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually code was big, loop was in a function. By mistake i just copied for loop without the function. Have edited question and included function there.